# Boost heap Setting user defined compare function

Tags: c++, boost, heap

Recently, I found Boost.Heap very useful in my project. But I could not find any example code showing how I can set up arbitrary compare function.

```
#include "boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp"

using boost::heap::fibonacci_heap;
int main(){
    fibonacci_heap<int> pq; //default compare function std::less<int>
}
```

For example, how can I set std::greater< int >?

The boost.heap document says that it can be set by setting an option. But I don't know what it means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef boost::heap::fibonacci_heap<
        int,
        boost::heap::compare<std::greater<int> > > MyHeap;
```

The documentation does not show how to specify options. I had to dig through the unit test source code to find out the correct usage syntax.

Comment: When I type defined following your answer, I got an error message "Template argument 2 is invalid". I just copy and paste your code. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's an end angle bracket missing in my answer. Edited answer.